# Windows server 2008 R2 nas connection

Tags: network-attached-storage

I am a student and i'm experimenting with my own home server running windows server 2008 R2.
Now i have a NAS in my network an i can connect with it trough my server but only if i am on the administrator account.

My own account is in the administrators group but can't establish a connection with the NAS unless the administrator account has already connected.

How do i make my own account connect with the NAS without first connecting with the admin account.

The error message on my account:

An error occurred while reconnecting Y: to
\NAS\Download
Microsoft Windows Network: The user name could not be found.
This connection has not been restored.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question. Are you using Active Directory? What type of NAS is this?

Comment: Please read our [faq] and also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what device the NAS is, but it sounds like its either not using AD authentication, or you're not mapping the drive on the NAS with an account that exists locally on it.